# Emmet Parser for PHP

Tags: php, parsing, handlebars.js, markdown, emmet

Is there a php parser to take emmet style markdown code and parse it into html?

I find myself writing code like.

```
$htmlBlock .= '<div id="'.$myDivId.'">';
$htmlBlock .= '<ul>';
foreach( $myArray as $listItem){
    $htmlBlock .= '<li>' . $listItem . '</li>';
}
$htmlBlock .= '</ul>';
$htmlBlock .= '</div>';
echo $htmlBlock;
```

With some nesting, conditions, attributes, and classes it gets very tedious and complicated.  The worst part is remembering to close tags and calculating when a tag needs to be closed.

I am familiar with [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) but that gets pretty messy too with nested loops and conditionals.  I would like to avoid tags and HTML syntax entirely.  If fact, I feel crazy for even writing it.

Those that are familiar with emmet know that

```
#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a{Item $}
```

Will parse into

```
<div id="page">
<div class="logo"></div>
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

It would be so much easier to write

```
 $emmet = #$myDivId ul li{$myArray}
```

Even being able to write this would be pretty sweet.

```
 $emmet = #$myDivId ul
 $emmet .= foreach ($myArray as $listItem) li{$listItem}
```

I see a lot of markdown parsers for php, and [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/demo) looks cool, but I don't want to have to learn another language.  I like outputting html in shorthand syntax.

It seems like stylus, sass, and less tackled with problem in css, but html was forgotten.  Which is amazing to me because HTML is so much more verbose.

I feel like the ideal solutions would be a php emmet parser that allows variables.  Does anyone know of one? If not, I will start a Github repo and go to work.

Comment: If heredoc's giving you a hard time, did you try [**nowdoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)? It seems like it would do the job.

Comment: Heredoc is actually better for my uses.  But, I want to use shorthand syntax anyway.

Comment: you might want to look into HAML...

Answer (score 0):

I've only found two projects with the right focus, but one never really got started.

https://github.com/lavoiesl/php-emmet

This one could do the trick.  I will explore it.

https://code.google.com/p/php-zen-coding/wiki/OverviewUsage

Answer (score 0):

Here is a composer package that might work for you, it says it's html rendering in php inspired by hyperscript and has emmet like features.

https://github.com/spatie/html-element

This code:

```
el('div.container > div.row > div.col-md-6', 'Hello world!'));
```

Will render this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    Hello world!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Supposedly anyways! I have not yet used this, but I definitely will for my next project. Hope this helps!

https://github.com/spatie/html-element

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/artemBilik/emmet

Usage 'div>p.myP{some text}+p#myPersonalP{another text}

And the same for javascript

https://github.com/artemBilik/js_emmet